# How to match a string to another string in an array list and print the match?

Tags: java, arrays

Ok, here is the question I have. I'm trying to allow a user to search my contact list for a matching contact by "lastname, email, and zipcode" I've tried using "matches" and "equals" function, with a Boolean that if I have a match, it will print out the string/contact with the match. However, it doesn't print out anything. Am I using the wrong function to match the contacts? My match function is found in ContactList.java below under the method searchEmail.

MainActions.java

```
    case 3:
        // read in last name here
        String userStringLastName;
        System.out.println("Enter the last name to search for: ");
        userStringLastName = reader.next();
        list.searchLastName(userStringLastName);
        break;
```

ContactList.java

```
/**
 * 
 * @param userStringLastName
 */
public void searchLastName(String userStringLastName) {
    // search last name

    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {
        Contact c = contacts.get(i);
        boolean b = userStringLastName.matches(c.getLastName());
        if (b == true) {
            System.out.println(c.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will not read this code. Please post relevant parts

Comment: I've also tried adding a string that prints out (no match found) if no match is found to see if it's reading my boolean as false, although their is a match in the list.

Comment: The programmers use the code reuse technique not to copy/paste.

Comment: Posted "relevant" parts.

Comment: imports is also relevant

Comment: print the string, match the string - what's the question?

Comment: Question was already answered. Not that hard to understand what the question was troll. Thanks for -1 my post. I could careless about a rep. My question was answered. :)

Comment: And for the idiots who didn't understand what the question was .. How to match a string to another string in an array list and print the match? HOW TO MATCH A "STRING" TO A "STRING" IN AN ARRAYLIST "AND" PRINT THAT "MATCHING" STRING. Seriously, how dumb can you get. Not a real question. Idiots can't read, that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
userStringLastName.toLowerCase().contains(c.getLastName().toLowerCase());
```

should work

Comment: Although your method will work. But is their a way to ignore case?

Comment: By lowering both cases, you actually are ignoring the cases.

Comment: As K Maertens said: this code simply ignores case, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I see. Tested it out. in fact did work without changing the case. A++